# (Python) TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, physics

When I compile the following program, Python throws a TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

This seems like a relatively straightforward program execution, but I can't seem to resolve it.

**Frequency**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def period(n):
    #masses
    m = [1] * n
    #lengths
    l = [2] * n
    M = sum(m)
    num = 2 * math.pi * n

for i in range(n):
    dem = dem + math.sqrt(g * m[i]/(l[i] * M)) 
return num/dem   

x = np.arange(1, 10,1)
y = period(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Let `M == sum from j==1 to n of the masses m_j`. I expect the program to simply display a plot of `period` where `period(n)` is simply defined by the sum from `1` to `n` of `sqrt(g * m_j/(l_j * M))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension to apply `period` function to each entry in the `x` array like this -

```
y = np.array([period(i) for i in x])
```

Also, you need to initialize both `dem` and `g` -

```
dem = 0.0
g = 9.8
```