# Converting array of ints to binary in Python3: "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted?"

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is not a duplicate question as far as I can tell. I will list related-but-different questions below.

Here's the code I'm trying to run, to convert an array of ints to binary as a single vectorized operation:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4],dtype=int)
b = bin(a)

----> 4 b = bin(a)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

...Um... I am literally operating on an "integer scalar array".  (And changing `dtype=int` to something like `dtype=np.int64` has no effect.)

I realize could do do this [with a loop (Python 2 question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138379/converting-integer-array-to-binary-array-in-python/36138631), or as a list comprehension (I understand that `bin` produces strings), so...this post is more a question of: Why can't I do it *as a single vectorized operation*, and why that error message? It seems so inappropriate in this case.   Any thoughts?

Related but non-dup questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138379/converting-integer-array-to-binary-array-in-python/36138631), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149307/python-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-inde), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902367/numpy-array-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-i), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337050/pandas-dataframe-fillna-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted).

The [docs for bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) read "Convert an integer number..." suggesting that arrays are just not allowed, and it's a Python function not a numpy function. (Ok, so then list comprehension or loop it is -- these just seem to be *slow* and I'm hoping for something *fast*).  But then why the error message about integer scalar arrays?

Thanks.

Comment: `bin` attempts to call `__index__` on the object if it is not an `int` as described in the docs you linked. An integer scalar array is something like `np.array(1)`. `np.array(1).__index__()` returns `1` but `np.array([1]).__index__()` gives the same `TypeError`.

Comment: To do the actual conversion, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57836960

Comment: `np.vectorize` and `map` and all those are still essentially loops and aren't going to show a magic "speedup". Also `np.vectorize` can slow your code down, especially if there's not an underlying numpy operation happening, so I'd stay away from that.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I even wrote in the OP, "I understand that bin produces strings". It's ok that you don't grasp the utility. ;-)  Not that it's any of your business, but I'm looking at binary representations of [Champerowne's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant).

Comment: Sorry @sh37211 for not catching that line the strings. I assumed since your code tried to pass a numpy array to `bin()` that you were just getting started and might not understand the basics. ;-) Just trying to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the function to every element of the numpy array -

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4],dtype=int)
b = np.array(list(map(bin,a)))
```

Additionally, you can check-out this link - [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: Hey, thanks!  And that link you shared helped me do a comparison of my own.  Not sure if comments will show images but: [perfplot comparison](https://imgur.com/DNHTufA) (also included whether to wrap the map in np.array or not).  So it looks like **I was wrong** and list-comprehension is plenty fast!  The first test I ran before creating this post had some latency that I hadn't accounted for.